# Why does $2 - \ln(9) = 2\ln\left(\frac{e}{3}\right)$?

Tags: calculus

I'm stuck with the following question:

$2 - \ln(9)$ equals:

a. $\frac{\ln(e^2)}{\ln(9)}$

b. $\ln(e^2 - 9)$

c. $\ln\left(\frac{e^2}{3}\right)$

d. $2\ln\left(\frac{e}{3}\right)$

The answer is d. Can anyone explain why this is the answer?

Comment: You should probably use the MathJax stuff (i.e., instead of writing 2 - ln(9) you should write $2 - \ln(9)$ or else no one will answer your question.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

d.) Is correct, since: $2\cdot\ln(\frac e3)= 2(\ln(e)-\ln(3))=2\ln(e)-2\ln(3)=2-\ln(3^2)=2-\ln(9)$

Comment: Formatting tip:  type `$\ln x$` to obtain $\ln x$.  For more information about typesetting mathematics on this site, see this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

$\log(a^m) =m*\log(a)$

$\log(\frac ab)=\log(a)-\log(b)$

$\log(e)=1$

$\log(9)=2*\log(3)$

$2-\log(9)=2[1-\log(3)]$

$=2[\log(e)-\log(3)]$

$=2*\log(\frac {e}{3})$